# "bounded" BatchBlock => ActionBlock. How to complete the proper way?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm trying to use a bounded batchblock linked to an action block.
I know when the feeding of items in the batchblock end and I want to trigger a completion chain.

The problem is: if my `BatchBlock<T>` is of a given `BoundedCapacity` I won't get all my items fired in the action block.

Here is a sample of my problem, it should (well in my understanding of TPL dataflow...) print 0 to 124 but it ends up printing 0 to 99.

There must be something I'm missing... Maybe `BoundedCapacity` means "drop items when queue count is over xxx..." if so how can I achieve a guaranteed maximum memory consumption?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int itemsCount = 125;
            List<int> ints = new List<int>(itemsCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
                ints.Add(i);

            BatchBlock<int> batchBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(50,new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions(){BoundedCapacity = 100});
            ActionBlock<int[]> actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int[]>(intsBatch =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                foreach (int i in intsBatch)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);               
            });
            batchBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

            // feed the batch block
            foreach (int i in ints)
                batchBlock.Post(i);
            // Don't know how to end the proper way... Meaning it should display 0 to 124 and not 0 to 99
            batchBlock.Complete();
            batchBlock.TriggerBatch();
            actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Post` on a block doesn't always succeed. It tries to post a message to the block but if the `BoundedCapacity` was reached it will fail and return `false`.

What you can do is use `SendAsync` instead which returns an awaitable task. If the block has room for your message it completes asynchronously. If it doesn't then the block returns a task that will complete when it does have room to accept a new message. You can await that task and throttle your insertions:

```
async Task MainAsync()
{
    var ints = Enumerable.Range(0, 125).ToList();
    var batchBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(50, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 100 });
    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int[]>(intsBatch =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        foreach (var i in intsBatch)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    });
    batchBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    foreach (var i in ints)
        await batchBlock.SendAsync(i); // wait synchronously for the block to accept.

    batchBlock.Complete();
    await actionBlock.Completion;
}
```